# rounded border around img doesnt show

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

[image]

as u can see the border is missing from the corners (red one). if i make it 4+ px thick then its ok but i need it 1px thin. why it is a problem? ist this property behaves by design like this?

the **html**

```
<div class="win" >  
<img class="rounded" src='red.jpg' />
</div>
```

and the **css**

```
.win{width:188px;float:left;margin:0 30px 25px 0;}
.win .rounded {
overflow: hidden;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
border:1px solid #000;  
-moz-border-radius: 7px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 7px; /* Safari and Chrome */
border-radius: 7px; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers, and now also Internet Explorer 6+ using IE-CSS3 */
}
```

**/*EDIT*/**

finally i have found a solution which makes exactly what i needed. i share the link maybe someone else has the the same problem:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-rounded-image-with-jquery

Comment: it should work in all major browser

Comment: As I can see I suggested the same solution as the one described in the article you share a link for, except jquery script. Isn't that so?

Comment: You cannot post answers within questions.  Please post the solution as an answer below and then "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `background-clip` css property. Try `background-clip: padding-box`. You should also add `-webkit-background-clip` and `-moz-background-clip` to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue using border-radius with images in most/all browsers. There are a number of online articles about this but I've not paid attention to them. You should Google for those.

Comment: @Sparky672 Not as lazy as those who want their googling done for them.

Answer (score -2):

If you want good rounded borders that will work with a large number of browsers, you could use image as a background for a div with needed css-properties.
Example (only border, nothing else):
**html**

```
<div class="card" style="background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center; width:150px; height:150px;"></div>
```

**css**

```
.card {
    border:1px solid #000;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```